# convert uint8_t to NSData

Tags: ios, rsa, nsdata, bytebuffer

I have implemented publickey privatekey RSA encryption in iOS application based on the examples provided on the Apple Developer site.

It works perfectly if I encrypt and return the `uint8_t cipherBuffer`, and then decrypt from the `uint8_t cipherBuffer`. However I need to store the encrypted data to an `.xcdata` model as `NSData`.

The problem I'm having is reliably converting the `uint8_t cipherBuffer` to `NSData` and/or converting the `NSData` back to `uint8_t` when it's time to decrypt. The decrypted data appears to be truncated.

This is how I'm converting the `uint8_t` encrypted buffer to `NSData`:

```
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cipherBuffer length:BUFFER_SIZE];
```

This is how I'm converting the encrypted `NSData` back to a `uint8_t` buffer when it is time to decrypt it:

```
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (uint8_t*)[cipherText bytes];
```

Comment: Just to make sure, cipherBuffer is a buffer which is malloc'd inside the method?

Comment: Are you using an automatic (function-scoped) array or you malloc some memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks jgh and Jody;

I changed the encryption method to "malloc" the buffer and tried several approaches to write the bytes to `NSData`, wound up with:

```
return [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)cipherBuffer length:CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

What finally fixed the issue was changing the way I was creating the `uint8_t` in the decryption method:

```
const uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (const uint8_t*)[data bytes];
```

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing how you're creating `cipherBuffer`, it's difficult to say exactly why it's not working.  However, from the documentation on `dataWithBytesNoCopy`:

> The returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it on deallocation. Therefore, bytes must point to a memory block allocated with malloc.

If you're just declaring cipherBuffer as

```
uint8_t cipherBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

it may explain your problems. Instead, use **`malloc`**:

```
uint8_t* cipherBuffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: The buffer is being allocated like this, i'll try malloc
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer;
    cipherBuffer = (uint8_t *)calloc(CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(uint8_t));

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are giving it a raw pointer, then re-using that pointer.

`dataWithBytesNoCopy:` wants to keep the pointer you give it. In fact, you must give it a pointer that you created with `malloc`, because it will free it when it's done with the data.

If you do not want the `NSData` object to take ownership, you should use **`dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:`**.